# MariaDB ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (10060)

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, windows-server-2008, pymysql

I construct DB server on the server computer (Windows Server) and use them with remote DB Access.
And DB contains very massive data (a single table which contains 30 columns and 5 million data)
The problem is sometimes I cannot connect to MySQL server (using root).
I tried everything in Stack Overflow threads but ends up with failure.

It seems it fails after python code(that I made) is halted while DB interaction.
What am I saying is...

```
db.connect(host, name, password, port, cursor...)
// Do some queries (insert, update) (lots of -- about 3 million rows will be added and modified if there are no problems.)
//<----------- python pops errors and exit improperly by dtype mismatch errors(I need to modify this code so that it works properly.)
db.close() <-- will not be executed because python is stopped by error.
```

What I want to know is, If DB is not closed properly while interaction, can this cause DB connection error?

When it came to happen, I always check servers (restart dbs, change memory setting in db). but fail to find out problems or solution.
But still can connect with db from Server Computer as localhost root
After that, I wait about several times(3-5 hours), and db operates normally(can connect to db)

Can I assume that failure within DB interaction causes this problem?

Addition ::
My Server Computer is not good. Use similar to 5th i5 CPU, 8GB RAMs

(From `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`:)

```
 connect_timeout    10
 deadlock_timeout_long  50000000
 deadlock_timeout_short 10000
 delayed_insert_timeout 300
 idle_readonly_transaction_timeout  0
 idle_transaction_timeout   0
 idle_write_transaction_timeout 0
 innodb_flush_log_at_timeout    1
 innodb_lock_wait_timeout   50
 innodb_rollback_on_timeout OFF
 interactive_timeout    28800
 lock_wait_timeout  86400
 net_read_timeout   30
 net_write_timeout  60
 rpl_semi_sync_master_timeout   10000
 rpl_semi_sync_slave_kill_conn_timeout  5
 slave_net_timeout  60
 thread_pool_idle_timeout   60
 wait_timeout   28800
```

Comment: The server is quite adequate.  The table is "big", but not "very massive".  It sounds like a timeout.  Exactly how long before it dies?  Look around for python timouts.  Check `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%';` in MySQL.

Comment: @RickJames Really thank you for answering. What should I exactly do for solving this problems? I can see 19 rows of timeout related records. Can you specify more? I think 'connect_timeout' looks need to be checked.(it's value is 10)And, when it fails in python code, also I cannot connect them with cmd mysql -uroot- p -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. Dose any relations between this?

Comment: My db values are below.

Comment: connect_timeout 10
deadlock_timeout_long 50000000
deadlock_timeout_short 10000
delayed_insert_timeout 300
idle_readonly_transaction_timeout 0
idle_transaction_timeout 0
idle_write_transaction_timeout 0
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout 50
innodb_rollback_on_timeout OFF
interactive_timeout 28800
lock_wait_timeout 86400
net_read_timeout 30
net_write_timeout 60
rpl_semi_sync_master_timeout 10000
rpl_semi_sync_slave_kill_conn_timeout 5
slave_net_timeout 60
thread_pool_idle_timeout 60
wait_timeout 28800

Comment: And how fast does it timeout? 10 seconds?  60 seconds?  28800 seconds (8 hours)?

Comment: When I try to connect to DB, it's about 10 seconds I guess. After type password, timeout message popped after about 10 seconds.

Comment: Let's try an experiment.  Change my.cnf section `[mysqld]` to include `connect_timeout = 80` and restart mysqld.  Now if it is 80 seconds, then it is very likely to be that setting.  That is a network problem, for which I don't have any good suggestions.

Comment: Also, please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'port';`  (I would expect `3306`.)

Comment: And, let's see all the arguments on `mysqld`.  Things like port, skip-networking, and bind-address are critical.

Comment: My DB Server became online now, -- I waited about a day. Can I test setting 'connect_timeout=80' now? Is it still meaningful test? And yes it uses port 3306. I think if it's hard to find out problems, I need to wait until SQL server cause same problems.Really appreciate your helps, When server is downed, I'll comment. I'll keep checking what you told for now. Thanks again.

Comment: 10060 on the client side means is "client side" timeout (WSAETIMEDOUT) . It is either connect timeout , or read timeout (not clear from the description). make sure you can connect to the server, and increase read timeout to be able to execute long queries. Changing anything in [mysqld] is not gong to help here.

Comment: Ok, it is clear from the description. Maybe you should increase the connect_timeout to be longer than 10 seconds, on the client (10 seconds is documented to be pymysql default). Perhaps you DB was too busy https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/connections.html

Comment: Really thanks for helping. I changed 'connection_timeout' to 30,  and tried to connect to DB server, but it disconnected after 20 seconds. Looks timeout is not a problem.One more things that happens when 1) Right after restart DB Server and try to connect (more than hour), 2) Connection fail to closed properly from python code, 3) There's term for reconnecting DB like when we go homes and try to connect nextday.

Comment: All situation is resolved if I wait several hours. But I need to do a lot :(. And when I success to connect, and make connection with cmd and do nothing but type 'show processlist' and kill not closed connections which should be closed while operation of code sometimes, it never fail to make new connection.

Comment: connect_timeout=300 also disconnected after 20 seconds.

Comment: I changed server computer, and tried again and it works find. Seems it is system spec problem. Thank you for your answers